Vue routeguard prevents supabase SIGN_IN event to occur after OAuth redirect
I've followed this tutorial on vueschool https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/use-supabase-auth-with-vue-js-3/ for supabase auth in vue3 app.
For signin i'm using this method:
const loginWithSocialProvider = async (provider: "facebook" | "github" | "google") => {
    return await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
        provider: provider,
        options: {
            redirectTo: window.location.origin
        }
    });
};


on my login page i have this simple button:
<ion-button expand="full" class="h-[60px]" @click="signIn">Google</ion-button>

and the signIn method in setup script:
const signIn = () => {
  loginWithSocialProvider('google')
}

the routeguard is a copy paste from the article just with removed fromEmail condition.
Now the problem is that when i try to log in it just reloads the login page back. When I've console logged the event and session in the onAuthStateChange i can see that there's only the INITIAL_SESSION  event but not the SIGN_IN event, seems like the routeguard is preventing the SIGN_IN event to occur.
router.ts looks like this:
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from '@ionic/vue-router';
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';
import TabsPage from '../views/TabsPage.vue'
import Login from '@/views/Login.vue';
import useAuthUser from "@/composables/useAuthUser";

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/tabs/tab1',
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: false,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/tabs/',
    component: TabsPage,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirect: '/tabs/tab1'
      },
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        component: () => import('@/views/Tab1Page.vue')
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        component: () => import('@/views/Tab2Page.vue')
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        component: () => import('@/views/Tab3Page.vue')
      }
    ]
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to) => {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useAuthUser();
  if (
      !isLoggedIn() &&
      to.meta.requiresAuth
  ) {
    return { name: "Login" };
  }
});

export default router


Does anyone please know how to overcome this ?
